# Fazer texto de outra div sumir

Tags: javascript, html

Fazer texto de uma div diferente sumir quando outro texto aparecer

```css
<style>
.descricao{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="textos1">
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga1').style.display='none'">Idade</span>
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga2').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga2').style.display='none'">Genero</span>
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga3').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga3').style.display='none'">Estado</span>
</div>

<div id="textos2">
<span class="descricao" id="vaga1">Recomendado a todas as idades</span>
<span class="descricao" id="vaga2">Masculino</span>
<span class="descricao" id="vaga3">Goiás</span>
</div>
```

Quero colocar um texto dentro da div textos2, mas que não seja fixo, ele tem que sumir quando aparecer os outros textos.

textos meramente ilustrativos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem, é só criar outro `span` com um `id` dentro da `div#textos2` e ocultar ela no `onclick` e mostrar no `onmouseout`:

```css
.descricao{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="textos1">
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga1').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='none'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='block'">Idade</span>
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga2').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='none'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga2').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='block'">Genero</span>
<span class="item"  onclick="document.getElementById('vaga3').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='none'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('vaga3').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('outrotexto').style.display='block'">Estado</span>
</div>

<div id="textos2">
   <span id="outrotexto">Outro texto</span>
<span class="descricao" id="vaga1">Recomendado a todas as idades</span>
<span class="descricao" id="vaga2">Masculino</span>
<span class="descricao" id="vaga3">Goiás</span>
</div>
```